# Drupal search yielded no results for anonymous user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, anonymous-users, drupal-search

I am using Drupal 7.50 Search returns no results for user either he is login or not(Except admin user).

Only admin user can Fetch the search result , but not the other user.

(1) successfully returns results for Administrator account.
(2) returns zero results ("Your search yielded no results") for authenticated regular user.
(3) returns zero results ("Your search yielded no results") for anonymous/un-authenticated visitor.

Use search selected the anonymous user and all users in admin user permissions area

Please Help me!!!![Search issue in drupal 7.50 version][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What content are you querying? If there are some results for Administrator account only, probably you have a permission issue. Please see [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/120614) more information.
PROTIP: If you are using some user fields, there is a permission called "View user information" which is by default only ticked for Admin users.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian K for your reply..

Comment: We have set the user permission for anonymous and authenticated user.
But the search results fetched only for administering user and remaining user  we can’t fetch the result. Its returns 'Search Result No match Found'

Comment: Are you using any modules like Display Suite or Groups? They add a lot of permissions to Drupal. I had exactly same problem when different Roles had different results count. Does View is starting to render for Authenticated User? Every View has in Block Settings Access Restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian K , We had a apache solr API configuration issue. We fixed by using java1.6 JDK, solr-3.

Comment: @RajeshBaskaran I am facing similar issue degraded java to 1.6 jdk still anonymous users not able to see the search results.